# PHP Preserving the URL parameters form page to page

Tags: php, url-parameters

I want to be able to test a website I am building using PHP that gets all its content from a database that uses point in time.  I have a series of pages that I use to maintain the content and assign effective dates.

The live website will not have access to a session.

I simply want to hack the URL with a parameter like so:

```
mywebsite.com/current.php?asof=2016-01-01
```

But I want this parameter to appear on all subsequent pages.

I could use cookies I guess but I want the visual cue.

Finally, some of the pages I navigate to will have additional parameters.

Can this be done?  If so, how?

EDIT:
Is there a way to edit the response by injecting URL parameters for any arbitrary response.

Answer (score 2):

If navigation is done only via links and forms, and you have no session, you could try injecting the params into all links and forms before rendering the html.

```
// set the asof value once upon starting navigation
$_GET['asof'] = '2016-01-01';

// then on all pages onward
// grab all links and inject all $_GET params
$html = preg_replace('/(href="[^"]+)"/', '$1?'.http_build_query($_GET).'"', $html);
// the same for forms
$html = preg_replace('/(action="[^"]+)"/', '$1?'.http_build_query($_GET).'"', $html);

echo $html;
```

This gets all the data passed in the query string ($_GET) and injects it into all links and forms. So every click on a link will propagate the $_GET params. Keep in mind that this is a rough implementation. This doesn't take into account links that already have query strings or pasting the url.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas  I will try it out over the next couple of days and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Set your cookie and then for every link you can do something like the following:

```
<?php
$asof = (isset($_COOKIE['asof']) ? 'asof=' . $_COOKIE['asof'] : '');
?>

<a href="/current.php?<?=$asof?>">link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas  I will try it out over the next couple of days and get back to you.

Comment: Sure thing. Just make sure that you only rely on either the cookie or the GET when you do your application logic. It would suck if you mix and match then decide to ditch one.